# How to make notifications at specific date in android application?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to make android application that notify the user at specific dates without caring about time ? how can i do it? please ,can anyone help?

Comment: By definition, you need to care about time. You are welcome to choose whatever time you think fits your needs best (e.g., midnight), but you need to specify a time. Otherwise, this is like asking how to set an alarm clock to ring on a certain day "without caring about time".

Comment: ok it's not problem ,, i can determine time ... but how can i do it ?

Comment: How you choose the time is up to you. If by "do it", you mean show a notification at a specific time, use `AlarmManager`.